# Get Label for Expresssion Func<T, U> Only Works for String Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, metadata, html-helper, func

I have a function that takes an **Expression< Func < TModel, Object >>** which I want to get the DisplayName from the metadata in the model. This works only for expressions with a signature of having **Func< TModel,String>**. **Func< TModel,Int>** or **Func< TModel,DateTime>** fails with the following error.

*Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.*

**Example Metadata Class with a few properties**

This is a sample **Metadata** class that supplies the **DisplayAttribute** for a few properties.

```
public class TestMetadata
{
    [Display(Name = "Area")]
    public Object Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Property")]
    public Object Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Int Property")]
    public Object Length { get; set; }
}
```

**Function to Extract DisplayAttribute Name Property**

This function works fine for the return values of string (Example **CustomDisplayFor(Html,m => m.Description)** returns the value "Area" as expected). However, fails with the noted error in the following circumstances.

```
public static String CustomDisplayFor<TModel>(HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, Object>> func) 
{ 
   return html.LabelFor(func);
}
```

Is there a way I can get the **DisplayAttribute** information from these other types of properties?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out that this works when you add another Type Reference for the return value.

**The Signature Becomes**

```
public static String CustomDisplayFor<TModel,TResult>(HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> func) 
{ 
   return html.LabelFor(func);
}
```

**Calling Code is the Same**

```
CustomDisplayFor(Html,m => m.Date) // This now works => "Date Property" returned
```